# Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema Error, when implementing one-to-many in Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, one-to-many

I'm making an Workout Log app.

And while creating a `one-to-many` relationship to Room DB, I got the following error.

```
25209-25261 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.lightweight, PID: 25209
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pre-packaged database has an invalid schema: Workout(com.example.lightweight.data.db.entity.Workout).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='Workout', columns={memo=Column{name='memo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, workoutId=Column{name='workoutId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, parentDailyId=Column{name='parentDailyId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[ForeignKey{referenceTable='DailyWorkout', onDelete='CASCADE', onUpdate='NO ACTION', columnNames=[parentDailyId], referenceColumnNames=[dailyId]}], indices=[]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='Workout', columns={parentDailyId=Column{name='parentDailyId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, memo=Column{name='memo', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, workoutId=Column{name='workoutId', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, title=Column{name='title', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

**The following image is the current table.**

[image]

---

**DailyWorkout : Recorded by date.**

| DailyLog |
| --- |
| dailyId: Long |
| date: String |
| bodyPart: String |

**Workout : It is a one-to-many relationship with DailyWorkout.**

| Workout |
| --- |
| workoutId: Long |
| title: String |
| memo: String |
| parentDailyId: Long |

**WorkoutSetInfo : Sets information for each Workout. It is a one-to-many relationship with Workout.**

| WorkouSetInfo |
| --- |
| id: Long |
| set: Int |
| weight: String |
| reps: String |
| unit: String |
| parentWorkoutId: Long |

---

**In Code**

**DailyWorkout**

```
@Entity
data class DailyWorkout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val dailyId : Long = 0,
    val date: String,
    val bodyPart: String,
)
```

**Workout**

```
@Entity( 
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = DailyWorkout::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("dailyId"), 
            childColumns = arrayOf("parentDailyId"), 
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Workout(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var workoutId: Long = 0,
    var title: String = "",
    var memo: String = "",
    val parentDailyId: Long = 0
)
```

**WorkoutSetInfo**

```
@Entity( 
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Workout::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("workoutId"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("parentWorkoutId"), 
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE 
        )
    ]
)
data class WorkoutSetInfo(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Long = 0,
    val set: Int,
    var weight: String = "0",
    var reps: String = "0",
    var unit: String = "kg",
    val parentWorkoutId: Long = 0
)
```

*Currently, one-to-one of Wokrout and WokroutSetInfo is implemented and works normally.*

***Error occurs when adding `foreignkey= ...` to Workout***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message indicates the schema of the pre-populated database **MUST** match the schema that room expects. *That is what is coded in the `@Entity` annotated classes.*

Rather than trying to establish the difference between the expected (schema according to the `@Entity` annotated classes) and then changing the schema of the pre-populated database. **It is simpler and 100% accurate to**:-

1. Compile the project when all the `@Entity` annotated classes have been finalised (and included in the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` annotation).
2. Inspect the **java(generated)** available via the **Android** view.
3. Inspect the class that is the same name as the `@Database` annotated class but suffixed with **`_Impl`**
4. Locate the **createAllTables** method. This will have a statement, for every component (tables, indexes) that executes some SQL. This SQL is exactly what Room expects and can be used as the basis for changing the table(s) in the pre-populated database.

- note ignore the room_master_table (CREATE and INSERT) as Room will create and populate this at run time. It stores a hash of the compiled schema, the hash being used to detect if the schema has been changed (if the compiled hash does not match the stored hash then the schema has been changed)

As an example, to circumvent the issue with the workout table, you could use the following in whatever tool you use *(SQlite Studio, DB Beaver or others)*:-

```
ALTER TABLE workout RENAME TO original_workout;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Workout` (`workoutId` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `title` TEXT NOT NULL, `memo` TEXT NOT NULL, `parentDailyId` INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`parentDailyId`) REFERENCES `DailyWorkout`(`dailyId`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE );
INSERT INTO workout SELECT * FROM original_workout;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS original_workout;
```

- WHERE the `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS workout ....` is the **SQL copied from the generated java**.

You may have to use this for other tables (certainly for WorkoutSetInfo as you are also adding foreign keys to this table according to your screen shot).

You then need to close the database, copy it and use the copy to replace the database in the asset folder.

Copying your `@Entity` annotated classes and then adding:-

```
@Database(entities = [DailyWorkout::class,Workout::class,WorkoutSetInfo::class], exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class WorkoutDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

}
```

- added as it is the `entities` parameter that determines what classes are actually considered as tables and thus determines the generated java.

Then after compiling the project (CTRL + F9) then :-

[image]

Comment: I have summarized what I understand. Please make sure I understand correctly.

**1.** expected is the schema of the `@Entity` annotated class.

**2.** Based on the `@Entity` annotation class, the `@Database annotation class_Impl` Java class is created.

**3.** The SQL in the `createAllTables` method is based on the `@Entity` annotated class.

**4.** Use (copy) the SQL query in the method and copy it to the DB tool as it is.

**5.** Then copy and paste the completed DB file to the asset folder.

I understand that much, right?

Comment: @ybybyb yes, and perhaps another important thing. Always keep backups of the database file so you can redo/retry.

Comment: thanks. However, I have additional questions.

**1.** Should the Workout table not exist in the database file to execute the query in your answer?

**2.** Why do you do compiling the project (CTRL + F9) at the end?

Comment: @ybybyb **1.** the workout file must exist for it to be renamed and be used as the data source (assumed that it contains data) for the insert into the new workout table with the correct schema. **2.** it is compiling the project that generates the java for the **_Impl** classes.